# Passing data from jsp to controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have one jsp for user to enter puppy information.

```
<FORM  action="/publish" method="post" commandName="puppy" >
    <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding="0">
       <% String[] textFields = {"category", "name", "gender", "age", "price"};
            for (int j= 0; j<textFields.length; j++){      %>
            <tr>  <td> <%=textFields[j]%>:                        </td>
                  <td> <input type=text name=<%=textFields[j]%>>  </td>
            </tr>
           <% } %>
    </table>
    <input type = "submit" value="submit">
</FORM>
```

i have a puppy object containing category, name, gender,age,price.

In controller, I want to get the puppy information written by user

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/publish")
public String publish (@ModelAttribute("puppy") Puppy newP, BindingResult result){
        System.out.println("Puppyname: " + newP.getName());
        return "redirect:publish.jsp";
}
```

This doesnt work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you are already rendering JSP you are already in the VIEW phase (meaning it is too late).  It looks like you are using Spring MVC so take a look at RedirectAttributes http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html this allows data to be send from the previous VIEW to the next controller via a redirect.  Google the terms will probably help you more than SO comment/answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Spring MVC tag lib. Put an input in your form for each property of your `Puppy` class, for example:

```
<s:input  path="name" />
```

Obviously you must have `category`, `name`, `gender`, `age`, `price` properties in your `Puppy` class and public accessors for them.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3.1+ RedirectAttributes (aka FlashAttributes) are your friend.

Random blog link with example http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html